# Getting error while running Spring boot app via Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

While running the code getting whitelabel page error as shown in Postman Kindly help with what is going wrong:
Note : All classes are below main class as per few checked solution. Issue remain same with `@ComonentScan` too.

> Postman error :
> {
> "timestamp": "2022-08-05T12:08:42.938+00:00",
> "status": 404,
> "error": "Not Found",
> "path": "/dept/"
> }

Json given:

```
{
"deptName":"XYZ",
"address": "XYZ"
}
```

Entity code:

```
package com.microservice.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
//import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Entity
@Data

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Department {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int departmentId;
    

    private String deptName;


    private String address;

}
```

Service:

```
package com.microservice.Service;

import com.microservice.Entity.Department;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.microservice.Repository.DepartmentRepository;

@Service

    public class DepartmentService {
        @Autowired
        private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;
    
    
    
        public Department getByID(int departmentId)
        {
            return departmentRepository.findByDepartmentId(departmentId);
        }
    
        public Department saveDepartment(Department department) {
            return departmentRepository.save(department);
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
package com.microservice.FController;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import com.microservice.Entity.Department;
import com.microservice.Service.DepartmentService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dept")
public class DepartmentController {

  @Autowired
    private DepartmentService departmentservice;




 @PostMapping("/")
    public Department saveDepartment(@RequestBody Department department){
        return departmentservice.saveDepartment(department);
    }

@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Department getByID(@PathVariable("id") Integer departmentId  ) {
    System.out.println("Inside get id controller method");

    return departmentservice.getByID(departmentId);
}



}
```

Repository:

```
package com.microservice.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.microservice.Entity.Department;

public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department,Integer> {

     Department findByDepartmentId(int departmentId);
}
```

Main Class:

```
package com.microservice.Departmentservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DepartmentServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DepartmentServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're missing the most important information, i.e. the request you send with postman.

Comment: The screenshot is removed info is post -body-raw-json and above mentioned json data

Comment: I see but the request is not only the body, there is also a URL for example, which by the message it seems may be wrong.

Comment: http://localhost:9009/dept/

Comment: What if you try to change `@PostMapping("/depts")` and modify the URL to `localhost:9009/dept/depts`? Also, are you sure the service is started on port `9009` and not `8008` (did you explicitly configure that port else you'll default to that one)? Also, are you sure you're using the verb `POST` and not the default verb `GET`?

Comment: Yes in application.yml I specified port tried via changing that too. Also the mapping(path) given is as per above and tried with changing that too but still same.Kindly help. Tried Post only as checked.

Comment: May be a stupid question but are you sure the application is started? If you visit the link localhost:9009 what do you see?

Comment: You should try `localhost:9009/dept/` (notice trailing `/`) not `localhost:9009/dept` or just simply remove `/` from `@PostMapping("")` on top of `saveDepartment` method.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and seams to be correct. Just two check you must done this the **URL** that you request in *Postman*:

- *First*: Make sure that you make a `POST` request to the URL not `GET`
- *Second*: You add a slash character `/` in `@PostMapping("/")` on top of `saveDepartment` method. So, you have to make your post request as:

> ```
> http://localhost:9009/dept/
> ```

**Notice the trailing slash at the end of the request.**

Otherwise  you get 404 not found error if you missed this character `/`

---

Another way is just simply remove `/` from `@PostMapping("")` on top of `saveDepartment` method:

```
@PostMapping("")
public Department saveDepartment(@RequestBody Department department){
    return departmentservice.saveDepartment(department);
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response issue seems due to H2 database connectivity/configurations.